# Need to have many different URLS resolve to a single web page

Tags: html, http, post

And I don't want to use GET params.

Here are the details:

- the user has a bunch of photos, and each photo must be shown by itself and have a unuique URL of the form
  www.mysite.com/theuser/photoNumber-N
- I create a unique URL for a user each time they add a new photo to their gallery
- the web page that displays the user's photo is the **same code** for every user and every photo -- only the photo itself is different.
- the user gives a URL to Person-A but then Person-A has one URL to that one photo and cannot see the user's other photos (because each photo has a unique URL and Person-A was given only one URL for one photo)

I want the following URLS to (somehow) end up loading only one web page with only the photo contents being different:

```
 www.mysite/user-Terry/terryPhoto1
 www.mysite/user-Terry/terryPhoto2

 www.mysite/user-Jackie/JackiesWeddingPhoto
 www.mysite/user-Jackie/JackiesDogPhoto
```

What I'm trying to avoid is this:  having many copies of the same web page on my server, with the only difference being the .jpeg filename.

If I have 200 user and each has 10 photos -- and I fulfill my requirement that each photo is on a page by itself with a distinct URL -- right now I've got 2000 web pages, each displaying a unique photo, taking space on my web server and every page is identical and redundant disk-space-wasting HTML code, the only difference being the .JPEG file name of the photo to display.

Is there something I can do to avoid wasting diskspace and still meet my requirement that each photo has a unique URL? 
Again I cannot use GET with parameters.

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache, nginx, IIS? Are you using (or able to use) any server-side scripting, such as PHP?

Comment: Can your server rewrite URLs? If so, then you can convert these URLs into GET ones on the server side, without any action on the user side.

Comment: I'm developing on Apache and xampp but my production server I don't have so much control over.  My code is php, mysql, javascript so yes I can code in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on an Apache server, you can use Apache's mod_rewrite to accomplish just that. While the script you are writing will ultimately still be fetching GET variables (`www.mysite.com/photos.php?id=photo-id`), mod_rewrite will convert all the URL's served in the format you choose (`www.mysite.com/user-name/photo-id`).

Some ways you can implement it can be found [here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) and [here](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=.htaccess+rewrite&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cmsmarket.com%2Fresources%2Fdev-corner%2F97-useful-htaccess-rewrite-examples&ei=3do4T7e4GMSTiAeig83pAQ&usg=AFQjCNFNOal6M97Z97XfgSzXuXoNssrvoA), while the actual documentation on the Apache module itself can be found [here](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=.htaccess+rewrite&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpd.apache.org%2Fdocs%2Fcurrent%2Fmod%2Fmod_rewrite.html&ei=3do4T7e4GMSTiAeig83pAQ&usg=AFQjCNED76OUBD_NoAVXT3Ewd4jgzo-5cA).

Comment: Wow that is outrageously elegant.  Thanks.  mod_rewrite, not a friend of sellers of storage space. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS Manager. Go to the site hosted in IIS. Add additional binding for each url.

This will redirect all request the same location.